# How to revert changes to a kernel driver?

Tags: windows, kernel, driver

So i installed a kernel driver on my windows machine but accidentally left a while(1) in there (I know pretty stupid) and now OS just hangs when i start it. Is there a way to revert the driver to an earlier stage or revert to "previous commit" like we do in git? i can see thought WinDbg that it just hangs there. Even though i can break into it I can't seem to make it move on from that infinite loop.

Comment: boot from some livecd and remove file of driver manually.

Comment: boot to safemode goto c:\windows\system32\drivers and delete the .sys that you have created

Answer (score 0):

you'd typically have the below assembly controlling the while(1) loop. From inside the debugger change to assembly source mode and then alter rax register from 0 to 1. That should branch out the subsequent je.

```
xor         eax,eax
cmp         eax,1
je          xyz
```

Generally, you'd have to change the driver's start type to "disabled" and fix up other registry entries if it is a filter to any other boot critical devices (eg upper/lower filter)